# query to display data using where clause join and limit

Tags: php, codeigniter

Below query give output as

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [comment_ID] => 8 [ID] => 41 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [comment_ID] => 12 [ID] => 35 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [comment_ID] => 7 [ID] => 35 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [comment_ID] => 5 [ID] => 35 ) )
```

I need to display one [ID} with its 1st [comment_ID] no need of  2 and 3rd array of  data...instead of repeated [ID] with its [comment_ID] I need data for another [ID]

```
function latest_post() {       

    $this->db->select('comment_ID, ID');
    $this->db->from('user_posts');
    $this->db->join('user_comments', 'comment_post_ID = ID');
    $this->db->where('post_status', 1);
    $this->db->where('comment_approved', 1);
    $this->db->where('comment_rate', 3);
    $this->db->order_by("ID", "desc");
    $this->db->limit(4);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: Post your table schema to identify the columns

Comment: Can you please post expected output in expected format as well ?

Comment: Why have you got it broken up in to several $this->db-> sections?

Comment: Why you use $this->db->limit(4); insted of  $this->db->limit(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use group_by to remove repeataion of ID from result

```
$this->db->select('comment_ID, ID');
$this->db->from('user_posts');
$this->db->join('user_comments', 'comment_post_ID = ID');
$this->db->where('post_status', 1);
$this->db->where('comment_approved', 1);
$this->db->where('comment_rate', 3);
$this->db->group_by("ID");
$this->db->order_by("ID", "desc");
$this->db->limit(4);
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```

This will result single record for each ID

Answer (score 0):

When using a join try to always define the table in the select.

```
$query = $this->db->select('user_posts.comment_ID, user_posts.ID')
->from('user_posts')
->join('user_comments', 'user_comments.comment_post_ID = user_posts.ID')
->where('post_status', 1)
->where('comment_approved', 1)
->where('comment_rate', 3)
->order_by("ID", "desc")
->limit(4)
->get();
return $query->result();
```

Also note that I removed the repeating $this->db